# Java Frame class inheritance

Tags: java, class, inheritance, applet, frame

If newbie questions are allowed, could someone point me to online documentation to show how the Java Frame class inherits from Applet? My instructor has advised that it does (i.e., that Frame does inherit from Applet), at least for Java 2 ver. 5.0, but I am not finding online documentation to show it. I am new to Java and want to understand how to research it. I am looking on website
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html

Comment: It doesn't. Either your instructor is wrong, or you've misunderstood him.

Comment: I'd very much doubt of everything a teacher says if he still uses Java 5 and applets to teach Java. Java 5 is 5 years old, and unsupported. Nobody uses applets, and there's no reason to teach them. Sigh...

Comment: Time to find a new course.  Is this high school or uni?

Comment: I thought OOP using Java at a university and I discarded the whole section about Applets.  Instead, I just added it as a footnote. If you get a job offer that requires you to work with Applets, my professional suggestion to you is to apply somewhere else. If it is a bad thing for an institution to teach archaic technology, it is worse for a business to be using it today.

Comment: Thank you all immensely for these responses. This is a college level course (I have a degree, but back learning new skills). Your responses have confirmed my own research. Just FYI my instructor stands by the original assertion that Frame inherits from Applet (I double checked and have it in writing).

Comment: In addition to the thoughts of @JBNizet & hfontanez, please refer the instructor to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0):

check this out [Frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) and this [Applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) and look up in the left to see the tree of inheritance. Both inherit from `Container` but `Frame` inherits from `Window`(from AWT) and `Applet` inherits from `Panel`(AWT). I am not an expert, still a student but I'm pretty sure that `Frame` and `Applet` does not inherit from one another. From my knowledge a Frame is just a window on a machine(PC) with auto drawn buttons for Minimize,Maximize,Close  and a `Content Pane` where you put your stuff(TextFields etc...). An `Applet` I know that *works* like a `Frame` but within a browser.

Comment: Logically should not, because an Applet needs to run in a browser.  Frame is the outer container in Swing.  Why are people still emphasizing AWT?  Supplanted by Swing 15 years ago (yes, I know it is built on top of it).  Applets were huge in 1995; don't matter now.  Why would I prefer Swing over a web UI?

Comment: You are right and you pretty much defined what a Frame is. Is not the question why would you prefer Swing over web UI, rather the reason for using Swing is that many companies still use it or they have code that needs to be maintained or modified written in Swing. Anyway from the book I read, updated now to 2014, the author Danie Liang, has written in the introductory chapter to GUI that Swing is dead and Oracle does not offer support for it anymore. They use instead JavaFX a new technology designed for internet.I have not documented about this because at my University we are still doing Swing

Comment: Having taught this in college, what typical textbooks show is a way to create simple programs that could be initialized as an `Applet` or a `Frame` depending how they are launched. I am not sure what your professor said, but if he used **explicitly** the word inherit, he was grossly mistaken.

Comment: JavaFX?  Response to Flash - two more dead technologies.

Comment: *"..from the book I read, .. the author Danie Liang, has written .. that Swing is dead.."*  Really?  It contains patently wrong information.  Better to use that book as a door stop, or as kindling (it must be good for something).